# Using begin and end in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can I somehow change the JavaScript language such that the word `end` equates to the `}` symbol and `begin` equates to `{`?

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting this...it's a valid question.

Comment: I was about to tweet "There goes my rep on StackOverflow".

Comment: Sure, give [these guys](http://www.ecma-international.org/) a call - I'm sure they'll get it in the next version.

Comment: It's not that it's an invalid question, but I spent a minute imagining what even a simple function would look like and my head exploded.

Comment: No, I mean with some sort of prototype voodoo magic or something.

Comment: if () begin end else begin end

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I don't know: I was just looking at the code and thinking "} means end, and { means begin".  I think it was a moment of brilliance.

Comment: A good thing to do when learning a new language is to learn the new language the way it's actually used by proficient programmers. Don't try to make it look or work like your current favorite language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't. The best you could do is have a script that modifies another script with an invalid `type` and changes it to a valid `type` so you'd get the *effect*, kind of.

```
<script type="text/x-algolscript">
    function hello() begin
        alert("Hello, world!");
    end
    hello();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('script'), function(script) {
        if(script.type === 'text/x-algolscript') {
            var oldParent = script.parentNode;
            var oldNext = script.nextSibling;
            oldParent.removeChild(script);
            script.textContent = script.textContent.replace(/\bbegin\b/g, '{').replace(/\bend\b/g, '}');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            oldParent.insertBefore(script, oldNext);
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is context-insensitive, however, and will gladly change your strings and such.

**Bonus:** Minified and more browser-compatible version:

```
!function(s,i,t,e,l,p,o,n){for(l=s.length;i<l;i++)((e=s[i]).type==='text/x-algolscript')&&t.push(e);for(i=0;i<t.length;i++)o=(e=t[i]).parentNode,n=e.nextSibling,o.removeChild(e),p='textContent',e[p]||(p='innerText'),e[p]=e[p].replace(/\bbegin\b/,'{').replace(/\bend\b/,'}'),e.type='text/javascript',o.insertBefore(e,n)}(document.getElementsByTagName('script'),0,[]);
```

Comment: Yeah right, and what about `var s = "Here I begin the story"`?

Comment: @Andrey: *"This is context-insensitive, however, and will gladly change your strings and such."*.

Comment: Second problem is that begin/end are valid identifiers in JS so this will mess up a code (var begin;) instead of producing error.

Comment: @Andrey: Sure, they're valid identifiers in JavaScript, but they won't be valid identifiers in this theoretical language with `begin` and `end` as keywords.

Comment: @icktoofay that is what I am saying. But this code will not inform you of error.

Comment: @Andrey notice `type="text/x-algolscript">` the first script is NOT interpreted as javascript

Comment: without a lexer/parser this would never work correctly. Same problem as 100% reliable regexing comments (in EcmaScript).

Answer (score 5):

You can write your own transcompiler that will parse our Pascalesque Javascript and output traditional Javascript. You can either just replace the words `begin`/`end` with brackets or use something more advanced like [Jison](http://zaach.github.com/jison/).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [META II](http://www.bayfronttechnologies.com/mc_tutorial.html).

> ...make a lot of compilers - and it's all going to be easy. No Ajax,
>   Active X, DLLs, SOs, ASP, CGI, Java, plugins, modules, XML, cookies,
>   PHP, Perl, Python, magic shell operations, world wide standard du
>   jour, or intergalactic domination plans are necessary - just plain
>   JavaScript in frames. Also you will be able to move the compiler you
>   build off these web pages and into your programming language of choice
>   by cutting and pasting. After all a compiler is just a program that
>   reads text and writes text or binary.

Just as an idea.

---

Alternatively, you might want to use the folloing (dubious) coding-style (to get familiar with ES's grammar) in the beginning:

```
function name(args){//begin
  // your code here
}//end

while(L--){//begin
  // your code here
}//end
```